# Bound the norm of the partial trace of an operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H=H_1 \otimes H_2$ a composite Hilbert space and let $A, B$ bounded linear operators on $H$, and we can assume they are trace class. Let $A_2$ we denote the operator on $H_2$ obtained by taking the partial trace on $H_1$, i.e. $A_2 = \mathrm{tr}_1 (A) \in B(H_2)$. Assume that we know there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ so that $$ ||A-B||_{B(H)} < \varepsilon. $$ Can we deduce a similar bound for $$ ||A_2 - B_2 ||_{B(H_2)} ? $$

---

**Notes**:
1) The **finite dimensional case** $\dim (H_1) = n_1$, $\dim (H_2) = n_2$, $\dim (H) = n$ all finite would be fine (but if you have a hint or source for an answer in the general case I'd appreciate!).

2) (My approach) Choose the Frobenius (or Hilbert-Schmidt) norm, $$ ||A||_{B(H)} = \sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(A^\dagger A)}$$ and let $C=A-B$. We know that $ ||I_1 \otimes C_2 ||_{B(H)} = ||I_1||_{B(H_1)} ||C_2||_{B(H_2)}$ (cf. Reed Simon Vol. 1 page 299), then 
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
||C_2||_{B(H_2)} &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_1}} ||I_1 \otimes C_2||_{B(H)} \\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_1}} ||C - (I_1 \otimes C_2) - C ||_{B(H)} \\
&\leq& \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n_1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_1}} ||C - (I_1 \otimes C_2)||_{B(H)} 
\end{array}
$$
and expect to bound the term on the right by $\alpha ||C||_{B(H)}$. To see what is going on I put
$$
C = C^{(1)}_1 \otimes C^{(2)}_1 + C^{(1)}_2 \otimes C^{(2)}_2 
$$
(taking enough terms of these form should be fine to represent an arbitrary $C$). A calculation gives
$$
||C - (I_1 \otimes C_2)||_{B(H)} = ||(C^{(1)}_1 - (\mathrm{tr} C^{(1)}_1) I_1)\otimes C_1^{(2)} + (C^{(1)}_2 - (\mathrm{tr} C^{(1)}_2) I_1)\otimes C_2^{(2)}||_{B(H)}
$$
how close this is to $||C||_{B(H)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bound on the norm of partial trace of operator that depends on the type of norm and the size of the Hilbert space you traced out. For the Schatten $p$-norm, which is defined for $p\ge1$ as
$$\|A\|_p=\left[\text{Tr}(|A|^p)\right]^{1/p}$$
one can show a bound, due to [Rastegin](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3853), where
$$\|\text{Tr}_1(A)\|_p \le [\dim(H_1)]^{(p-1)/p} \|A\|_p$$
This bound can be made dimension-independent by choosing $p=1$, in which case the norm is the trace norm. But if you choose $p=2$, which gives the Frobenius norm, you'll have a dimension-dependent bound.

Comment: You get a dimension-independent bound also for $p=\infty$, right?

Answer (score -1):

*(a colleague just helped me to arrive at the answer. Moreover, it seems to me that it carries over to the infinite dimensional space so long as the partial trace is well defined).*

Let $ C = \sum_{ij} \alpha_{ij} e_i \otimes e_j,$ where $e_i$ is a matrix with only one non-zero entry equal to one, so we have this basis for the complete space. We calculate 
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
||C_2||_{(B(H_2),||\cdot||_F)}^2 &=& ||\sum_{ij} \alpha_{ij} \mathrm{Tr}(e_i) e_j ||_{(B(H_2),||\cdot||_F)}^2 \\
&=& \sum_{ij} |\alpha_{ij}|^2  |\mathrm{Tr}(e_i)|^2 \\
&\leq& \sum_{ij} |\alpha_{ij}|^2 = ||C||_{(B(H),F)}^2
\end{array}
$$
where we used that $\mathrm{Tr}(e_i)$ is either one or zero. We conclude that $||C_2|| \leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: This proof is flawed because using the Frobenius norm means that $\|\sum_{ij} \alpha_{ij}\text{Tr}(e_i)e_j\|^2 = \sum_j |\sum_i\alpha_{ij}\text{Tr}(e_j)|^2$, which isn't what you've written.

Comment: I see your point, thanks. Now, since $\sum_j |\sum_i \alpha_{ij} Tr(e_i)|^2 \leq \sum_{ij} |\alpha_{ij}|^2 = ||C||^2$, then this dimension-independent bound in the Frobenius norm still holds, I think.

Comment: Um I don't think so. It isn't true that $|\sum_i \alpha_{ij}Tr(e_j)|^2 \le \sum_i |\alpha_{ij}|^2$. A simple counter example would be taking $\alpha_{ij}=1$, so on the left hand side you have something $O(n^2)$, and on the right hand you have $O(n)$, where $n$ is the dimension of the first Hilbert space that's traced over. A more obvious counterexample is to take the operator $C=P_1\otimes P_2$, where $P_i$ is a projector with rank $r_i$. Then $\|C_2\|^2_F = r_1\sqrt{r_2} \not\le \|C\|^2_F=\sqrt{r_1r_2}$

Comment: Sorry that should be $\|C_2\|_F = r_1\sqrt{r_2} \not \le \|C\|_F = \sqrt{r_1r_2}$, without the square. This example also illustrates that the Rastegin bound is tight, since we effectively have $\dim(H_1)=r_1$